# Locating Reihngnahting/Reihmahting in Germany

Tags: germany, palaeography, baden-wuerttemberg

I'm hoping someone can help me read a place name. I found the attached on Ancestry in Baltimore, Passenger Lists, 1820-1964:

```
Name Georg Muggenthaler
Birthdate 1826
Age 32
Arrival Date Jul 1858
Port of Departure Bremen, Germany
Ship Name Gaston
Port of Arrival Baltimore, Maryland
```

I can't read what is written for Nationality (Reihngnahting or Reihmahting??). I believe they were from Wurttemberg. Google hasn't been very helpful in identifying a place when I try different spellings.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since you're on Ancestry, you should look for the departure record in Bremen. That will give you another chance at deciphering the name (in another person's handwriting)

Comment: Thank you. I just had a look, but the date I need isn't covered in the departure records in Bremen. I did just find a newspaper article in German and it's easier to read (I attached it above in my initial query). It looks like it says Reihnprechting, but I still can't find any such place.

Answer (score 2):

In the record it says Reihnprechting as you found out via the newspaper entry. There is a Reinprechting in Bavaria near Deggendorf (https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/1083604995). This might fit because the name "Reihnprechting" sounds either Bavarian or Austrian to me. Also the name "Muggenthaler" sounded Austrian to me, but would also fit to Bavaria.

Comment: Thank you! I'd say that's right.